# Decimal to Hexadecimal Translator Lua

Tags: lua, hex, decimal

I started making a decimal to hexadecimal translator in Lua to try out what I know; I've read Lua can do this by itself but I wanted to reinvent it anyway.

I made a massive mistake and I'm not sure what the problem is:

```
file = "log"..os.date("%S.%M.%H%p.%d.%m.%Y")..".txt"
do
    log =  io.open(file, "w")
    io.output(log)
end

dechexint = remainder

function hexTracker()
  remainder = result % 16
  result = result / 16
  print(remainder, "\n")
  io.write(remainder, "\n")
end

function hexTranslator()
  if remainder == 11 
  then print("A")
  io.write("A")

  else
    if dechexint == 12
    then print("B")
    io.write("B")

    else
      if dechexint == 13
      then print("C")
      io.write("C")

      else
        if dechexint == 14
        then print("D")
        io.write("D")

        else
          if dechexint == 15
          then print("E")
          io.write("E")

          else 
            if dechexint == 16
            then print("F")
            io.write("F")
end
end
end
end
end
end
end

decint = io.read("*number")

  result = decint / 16
  result = decint % 16

while(result>0.1)
 do
   hexTracker()
   hexTranslator()
end
```

It does technically work, but...

```
input: 
4579

output:
3
0.1875
```

And it should give 11E3; Can anyone help?

Comment: Lua has a `elseif` keyword, to avoid nested `else` like your code. Moreover, try using local variables and parameter passing in functions to rewrite your code, it's too messy now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some serious issues. It has no way of looping through the digits of the number. It has mismatches on the hex digit mappings. It won't properly print decimal digits. The relationship between the `hexTracker` and `hexTranslator` functions doesn't work. Each of these alone will prevent it from working. There are additionally a handful of lesser issues that don't break it outright but which will lead to less maintainable code. Some of these include the heavy use of global variables, the deeply nested `if / else if` construct, the excess `do` construct, using functions like procedures without parameters, etc.

I tried to keep this answer as close as possible in structure to what you had so you can more easily see what I changed and how it works. I focused more on making something that you can learn from than something that's perfect in every way, and I kept your `io.read()` method of inputting data and your output log file with the same name so it runs exactly the same.

I cleaned up a few of the constructs and simplified them in a (hopefully) transparent way. I dropped the `hexTracker()` function but made `hexTranslator()` recursive so that it will go through all the digits. Along with this I made `hexTranslator()` make use of both a parameter and a return value.

You can see the result here:

```
file = "/tmp/log"..os.date("%S.%M.%H%p.%d.%m.%Y")..".txt"
log =  io.open(file, "w")
io.output(log)

function hexTranslator(result)
  if result >= 16 then
    local intQuotient = math.floor(result / 16)
    local remainder = result % 16
    return hexTranslator(intQuotient) .. hexTranslator(remainder)
  else
    if result == 10 then
      io.write("A")
      return "A"
    elseif result == 11 then
      io.write("B")
      return "B" 
    elseif result == 12 then
      io.write("C")
      return "C"
    elseif result == 13 then
      io.write("D")
      return "D"
    elseif result == 14 then
      io.write("E")
      return "E"
    elseif result == 15 then
      io.write("F")
      return "F"
    else
      io.write(result)
      return tostring(result)
    end
  end
end

decint = io.read("*number")
print(hexTranslator(decint))
```

There are some ways of making this solution even better, and one that's worthwhile mentioning is replacing the whole `if / elseif` construct with a table lookup. This is shorter, easier to read, and faster to execute. Here's a quick way to do that, keeping everything else the same:

```
file = "/tmp/log"..os.date("%S.%M.%H%p.%d.%m.%Y")..".txt"
log =  io.open(file, "w")
io.output(log)

function hexTranslator(result)
  hexDigits = {[10] = "A", [11] = "B", [12] = "C", [13] = "D", [14] = "E", [15] = "F"}
  if result >= 16 then
    local intQuotient = math.floor(result / 16)
    local remainder = result % 16
    return hexTranslator(intQuotient) .. hexTranslator(remainder)
  else
    io.write(result)
    return hexDigits[result] or tostring(result)
  end
end

decint = io.read("*number")
print(hexTranslator(decint))
```

I hope this helps. Once you get familiar with it you'll likely want to remove the logging and may want to investigate options like supporting command-line entry of the number in addition to the method you have now.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(('%X'):format(12345678)) -- BC614E
```

Beware of overflow (0x100000000)

---

```
function tohex(num)
    local charset = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f"}
    local tmp = {}
    repeat
        table.insert(tmp,1,charset[num%16+1])
        num = math.floor(num/16)
    until num==0
    return table.concat(tmp)
end

print(tohex(0)) -- 0
print(tohex(1234567890123456))  -- 462d53c8abac0
```